# Maintain chart phpexcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I'm using phpexcel 1.8 to editing an xls.

In particular, the original file has 3 sheets
 First with a graph and values 
 Second with an image 
 Third with some values

Here's the code

```
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2 = $excel2->load('test.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A5', '999')->setCellValue('D7', '5');
$excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A7', '111');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('Nimit New.xlsx');
```

The resulting file is having the image in the 2nd sheet, but it doesn't have the graph in 1st sheet.

Is it possible to keep the graph (with updated values)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell PHPExcel to read charts

```
$excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$excel2->setIncludeCharts(true);
$excel2 = $excel2->load('test.xlsx');
```

and to include charts when writing

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel2, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(true);
$objWriter->save('Nimit New.xlsx');
```

as shown in the [examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/32chartreadwrite.php)